# laravel mongo db get data time as date in paginate

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

when i want get embed traffics  model , API respond publish wrong date format for embed model , and use `protected $dates = ['updated_at','created_at'];`
in my Traffic model but don't work and response still emitted wrong date and id format

**note:** when i use `get()` instead of `simplePaginate()` or `paginate()` query builder emitted right json format  !!!!!

**db:**
[image]

**paginate API respond:**

```
{
"current_page": 1,
"data": [

            {
                "lat": 59.56555555455,
                "lon": 35.54598994564,
                "type": "manual",
                "updated_at": {
                    "$date": {
                        "$numberLong": "1540712586000"
                    }
                },
                "created_at": {
                    "$date": {
                        "$numberLong": "1540712586000"
                    }
                },
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5bd5688a6925020c34006773"
                }
            }//.....
      ]
    }
```

**get() API respond:**

```
[
{
    "lat": 59.56555555455,
    "lon": 35.54598994564,
    "type": "manual",
    "updated_at": "2018-10-28 07:43:06",
    "created_at": "2018-10-28 07:43:06",
    "_id": "5bd5688a6925020c34006773"
},
{
    "lat": 59.56555555455,
    "lon": 35.54598994567,
    "type": "system",
    "updated_at": "2018-10-28 07:43:06",
    "created_at": "2018-10-28 07:43:06",
    "_id": "5bd5688a6925020c34006774"
}/...
]
```

**code**

```
     $userTrafic = Auth::user()->userTraffic()->firstOrFail();
     if ($userTrafic) {
       return   $userTrafic->traffics()->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->simplePaginate(20); //or get()
    }
    else  return response(['status' => false, 'message' => 'traffic\'s user not found'], 404);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change library :
Jenssegers\Mongodb\Relations\EmbedsMany.php

add `$sliced = $this->toCollection($sliced);` to line 294(before return) in `paginate()` method 
now you can get result like this:

```
{
"current_page": 2,
"data": [
    {
        "lat": 59.56555555455,
        "lon": 35.54598994564,
        "type": "system",
        "updated_at": "2018-10-28 08:12:36",
        "created_at": "2018-10-28 08:12:36",
        "_id": "5bd56f746925020c34006778"
    },
    {
        "lat": 59.56555555455,
        "lon": 35.54598994564,
        "type": "manual",
        "updated_at": "2018-10-28 08:13:55",
        "created_at": "2018-10-28 08:13:55",
        "_id": "5bd56fc36925020c34006779"
    },
    {
        "lat": 59.56555555455,
        "lon": 35.54598994567,
        "type": "system",
        "updated_at": "2018-10-28 08:13:55",
        "created_at": "2018-10-28 08:13:55",
        "_id": "5bd56fc36925020c3400677a"
    },
    {
        "lat": 59.56555555455,
        "lon": 35.54598994564,
        "type": "system",
        "updated_at": "2018-10-28 08:13:55",
        "created_at": "2018-10-28 08:13:55",
        "_id": "5bd56fc36925020c3400677b"
    },
    {
        "lat": 59.56555555455,
        "lon": 35.54598994564,
        "type": "manual",
        "updated_at": "2018-10-28 10:39:46",
        "created_at": "2018-10-28 10:39:46",
        "_id": "5bd591f26925020c3400677d"
    }
],
"first_page_url": "**********traffic/list?page=1",
"from": 6,
"last_page": 3,
"last_page_url": "**********traffic/list?page=3",
"next_page_url": "**********traffic/list?page=3",
"path": "**********traffic/list",
"per_page": "5",
"prev_page_url": "**********traffic/list?page=1",
"to": 10,
"total": 12
}
```